# Simplify Maybe expressions

Tags: haskell

I have the following code, and I think it is ugly:

```
loginCheck = do
  ml <- getPostParam "login" -- ml and mp :: Maybe ByteString
  mp <- getPostParam "password"
  if isJust ml && isJust mp
    then authAs (fromJust ml) (fromJust mp)
    else render "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")]
```

This code seems to be very imperative. Can I simplify it somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have suggested, `Applicative` could be nice here, as well as `MaybeT` depending on the context. A third thing you might keep in mind is that a pattern match failure in a `do` block binding calls `fail`.

This is what I would do:

```
loginCheck = do
  ml <- getPostParam "login" 
  mp <- getPostParam "password"
  fromMaybe (render "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")]) $
            authAs <$> ml <*> mp
```

Or a solution with `MaybeT`, albeit one with a different return value (again more context might show this to be a good approach or not):

```
getPostParamT = MaybeT . getPostParam
loginCheckT = do
    ml <- getPostParamT "login" -- ml and mp :: Maybe ByteString
    mp <- getPostParamT "password"
    liftIO $ authAs ml mp
   <|> (liftIO $ render "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")] )
```

...actually the above is rather hokey now that I look at it

Comment: I think your first approach is the cleanest of the lot. That's what I'd do, anyhow :).

Comment: +1 when I saw the type of logic required, I immediately thought `fromMaybe` + applicatives. Your `fromMaybe` solution is very clean. The MaybeT solution isn't bad; refactoring larger swaths of code to use MaybeT might be a good choice in OP's case.

Answer (score 12):

How about:

```
loginCheck = do
  ml <- getPostParam "login" -- ml and mp :: Maybe ByteString
  mp <- getPostParam "password"
  case (ml,mp) of
    (Just l, Just p) -> authAs l p
    _ -> render "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")]
```

Code that uses isJust and/or fromJust is nearly always bad style and slightly dangerous if you get the isJust check before fromJust wrong.

This can be be improved by

- Pattern matching, like above.  But if this is nested it gets ugly.
- Combinators, like fromMaybe can be more succinct.
- Using Maybe (and MaybeT) as Applicative or a Monad can avoid the ugly nesting.

Answer (score 4):

```
loginCheck = case (,) <$> getPostParam "login" <*> getPostParam "password" of
  Just (l, p)  -> authAs l p
  Nothing      -> render "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")]
```

perhaps? No. Oops.

```
loginCheck = do
  x <- (,) <$> getPostParam "login" <*> getPostParam "password" of
  case x of
    Just (l, p)  -> authAs l p
    Nothing      -> render "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")]
```

How annoying.

Comment: Re your second attempt: I think `x :: (Maybe ByteString, Maybe ByteString)`, not `x :: Maybe (ByteString, ByteString)`. The functor `<$>` and `<*>` are operating on is `IO`, not `Maybe`.

Comment: He just needs to add liftM2 before case: `liftM2 (,) <$> getPostParam "login" <*> getPostParam "password" >>= \res -> case res of ...`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is an improvement here, but maybe in some cases...

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

getPostParam' = MaybeT . getPostParam
render' x y = lift (render x y)
authAs' x y = lift (authAs x y)

loginCheck = runMaybeT $ 
        go `mplus` render' "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")]
    where
        go = do
            ml <- getPostParam' "login"
            mp <- getPostParam' "password"
            authAs' ml mp
```

Comment: I think it's cleaner to not define `render'` and `authAs'`, and just write the `lift`s inline, because such a function usually wouldn't be used more than once anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
loginCheck = do
  [ml,mp] <- mapM getPostParam ["login","password"]
  case liftM2 authAs ml mp of 
    Nothing         -> render "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")]
    Just authorize  -> authorize
```

This might seem strange because it pattern matches on a `Maybe (IO ())`, but this is perfectly sound. Or, using `maybe`:

```
loginCheque = mapM getPostParam ["login","password"] >>= \[ml,mp] -> 
              maybe message id (liftM2 authAs ml mp)
    where message = render "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")]
```

Comment: Oh, forgot about `fromMaybe` mentioned by `jberryman`; where I use `maybe` it should just be `fromMaybe message (liftM2 authAs...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
loginCheck = do 
  res <- return$ getPostParam "login" >>= \l -> -- ml and mp :: Maybe ByteString
                  getPostParam "password" >>= \p->
                   Just (l,p)
  case res of Nothing -> render "Msg" [("text", "Form incomplete")]
              (Just (l,p)) -> authAs l p
```